# TSclust package not found

Tags: r, time-series, tsclust

I don't know what goes wrong or how to fix it. Can you please help me with this?

```
> install.packages("TSclust")
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0100  342k  100  342k    0     0   394k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  394k

The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/bk/2b2d879912bgnl5s768s7crh0000gn/T//RtmpHpu6uh/downloaded_packages
> require(TSclust)
Loading required package: TSclust
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
  Reason: image not found
>
```

Here's info about my RStudio:

```
Version 0.99.473 – © 2009-2015 RStudio, Inc.
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/600.8.9 (KHTML, like Gecko)
```

And R:

```
dyn-72-33-222-106:~ mona$ R

R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
```

UPDATE:

```
> install.packages("TSclust")
also installing the dependencies ‘splus2R’, ‘ifultools’, ‘proxy’, ‘clv’, ‘rgl’, ‘misc3d’, ‘wmtsa’, ‘pdc’, ‘locpol’, ‘dtw’, ‘longitudinalData’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
                    binary    source needs_compilation
rgl              0.95.1201 0.95.1337              TRUE
longitudinalData       2.3       2.4             FALSE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2/splus2R_1.2-0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 190385 bytes (185 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 185 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2/ifultools_2.0-1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 961357 bytes (938 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 938 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2/proxy_0.4-15.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 142040 bytes (138 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 138 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2/clv_0.3-2.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 166056 bytes (162 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 162 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2/misc3d_0.8-4.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 151783 bytes (148 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 148 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2/wmtsa_2.0-0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 361400 bytes (352 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 352 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2/pdc_1.0.2.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 168385 bytes (164 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 164 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2/locpol_0.6-0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 104555 bytes (102 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 102 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2/dtw_1.18-1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 737519 bytes (720 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 720 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2/TSclust_1.2.3.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 353039 bytes (344 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 344 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/bk/2b2d879912bgnl5s768s7crh0000gn/T//Rtmp258LNe/downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘rgl’, ‘longitudinalData’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgl_0.95.1337.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2189241 bytes (2.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/longitudinalData_2.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 80334 bytes (78 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 78 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rgl’ ...
** package ‘rgl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E
checking for gcc... (cached) clang
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether __attribute__((visibility())) is supported... no
checking whether clang accepts -fvisibility... yes
checking whether  accepts -fvisibility... no
checking for libpng-config... yes
configure: using libpng-config
configure: using libpng dynamic linkage
checking for X... no
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rgl’ is not available for package ‘longitudinalData’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/longitudinalData’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘longitudinalData’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/bk/2b2d879912bgnl5s768s7crh0000gn/T/Rtmp258LNe/downloaded_packages’
> require(TSclust)
Loading required package: TSclust
Loading required package: wmtsa
Loading required package: splus2R
Loading required package: ifultools
Loading required package: MASS
Loading required package: pdc
Loading required package: cluster
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘longitudinalData’
> set.seed(12349)
> n = 100
> x <- rnorm(n) #generate sample series, white noise and a wiener process
> y <- cumsum(rnorm(n))
> w <- 20 #amount of equal-sized frames to divide the series, parameters for PAA
> alpha <- 4 #size of the alphabet, parameter for SAX
> #normalize
> x <- (x - mean(x)) /sd(x)
> y <- (y - mean(y)) /sd(y)
> paax <- PAA(x, w) #generate PAA reductions
Error: could not find function "PAA"
```

And rgl:

```
> library(rgl)
Error in library(rgl) : there is no package called ‘rgl’
> install.packages("rgl")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary    source needs_compilation
rgl 0.95.1201 0.95.1337              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘rgl’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgl_0.95.1337.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2189241 bytes (2.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘rgl’ ...
** package ‘rgl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E
checking for gcc... (cached) clang
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether __attribute__((visibility())) is supported... no
checking whether clang accepts -fvisibility... yes
checking whether  accepts -fvisibility... no
checking for libpng-config... yes
configure: using libpng-config
configure: using libpng dynamic linkage
checking for X... no
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/bk/2b2d879912bgnl5s768s7crh0000gn/T/Rtmp258LNe/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Maybe try updating your R version first, then installing the package

Comment: `rgl` seems to be causing this error... what happens if you run `library(rgl)`?

Comment: @tguzella please look at the update

Comment: @erasmortg I updated the R. Please look at the updated question

Comment: `install.packages("rgl", repos=NULL, type = "source")`

Comment: @erasmortg `> install.packages("rgl", repos=NULL, type = "source")
Warning: invalid package ‘rgl’
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: Do you have xcode on your machine? I've seen several solutions for your problem that point to it

Comment: I just downloaded the TSclust package and note that they do not import the `rgl` package into the NAMESPACE. I think you may want to email the authors about this... You can try to download the binaries, modify the NAMESPACE to do so, and install the package yourself. I just installed the package and didn't have a problem. Perhaps this is an old package version...

Answer (score 0):

> error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.
> ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’

This means you failed to install Xquartz. It’s not an R package. You need to download from its website and install from its installer pkg. It’s an equivalent of X11 on the Mac. ALWAYS update  quartz anytime you update R.

In your situation you might get away with install the ‘rgl’ pkg from binary image.